# Using tex4ht to convert from XeLaTeX source that uses Unicode-named macros to Word (.docx) format

Tags: macros, xetex, unicode, tex4ht, msword

I asked a very similar question several years ago on the `tex4ht` listserv and received a very helpful [answer](http://tug.org/pipermail/tex4ht/2016q3/001603.html) from Michal Hoftich. He described certain limitations for working with Unicode and `tex4ht` that I suspect may have been ironed out over the past few years of development. And so I am in essence asking the same question again (though some of the details are different) in hopes of learning whether there are simpler or more automated ways of converting my XeLaTeX document to `.docx` format.

## setup

### source file

First I produce a file that concatenates `head-simplified.tex` with the contents of `main.tex` and then `tail.tex`, where the three files are as follows:

`head-simplified.tex`:

```
%!TEX TS-program = xelatex
%!TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode

\documentclass[12pt]{memoir}
\usepackage{ifmtarg}
\usepackage{calc}

%Greek
\newcommand{\greek}[1]{#1}
\newcommand{\gk}[1]{#1}

%Arabic
\newcommand{\ar}[1]{#1}
\newenvironment{arab}{}{}

% Bibliography etc
\usepackage[american]{babel} 
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[notes,
        alldates=       comp,
        backend=        biber,
        bibwarn=        false,
        cmsdate=        both, % reprints: print `origdate` as well as `year`
        compresspages=  true,
        doi=            false,
        eprint=     false,
        ibidtracker=        true,
        inheritshorthand,       % feature added for me by D.Fussner
        isbn=           false,
        mincrossrefs =  2,
        shorthandibid,
        strict=     true,
        url=            true,
        usetranslator=  true,
        uniquename= true
    ]{biblatex-chicago}
\bibliography{word.converter.alexhistory-ent.bib}

\usepackage{textcomp} % For angle brackets `\textlangle` and `\textrangle`

\begin{document}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% code which C.V. Radhakrishnan added to make the unicode carry
% over smoothly to the word world.
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\makeatletter
\def\hshchr{\expandafter\@gobble\string\#}
\def\ampchr{\expandafter\@gobble\string\&}
\def\entity#1{\HCode{\ampchr\hshchr#1;}}
\makeatother
```

`main.tex`:

```
\newcommand{%
\ص%
}[1]{$\rangle$#1$\langle$}


This is a test file using a macro whose name uses Arabic Unicode characters:
\ar{%
العربية%
}.
Then we can try it as a block quote:
\begin{quote}
\begin{arab}
% Text with Unicode macro:
أن يبد\ص{أ}
% Text without Unicode macro:
%أن يبدأ
\end{arab}
\end{quote}
If that doesn't work, here is some non-Arabic Unicode: \emph{kitābat al-ʿarabiyyah bi-l-ḥurūf al-lātīniyyah}, \gk{καὶ τὸ στοιχείοις Ἑλληνικοῖς γράφειν}...
```

`tail.tex`:

```
\end{document}
```

### conversion

Then I use a script called `texbody2word` that automates the instructions that I owe to C.V. Radhakrishnan and Michal Hoftich and others who have helped make this conversion possible:

```
#!/bin/bash

#This takes a tex file with only the body
#(no header or `\end{document}`) and compiles
#it as a PDF

#filename without extension `.tex`
filename=$(basename "$1")
filename="${filename%.*}"
converterdir="/Users/alexandre/Dropbox/scripts/texbody2word-files"

#produce standalone tex file
cat $converterdir/head-tail/head-simplified.tex $filename.tex $converterdir/head-tail/tail.tex > $filename.out.tex

#convert unicode to ascii codes in tex file and bib file
perl $converterdir/utf2ent.pl $filename.out.tex > $filename.out-ent.tex
perl $converterdir/utf2ent.pl ~/Dropbox/bib-dbs/alexhistory.bib > word.converter.alexhistory-ent.bib

#apply tex4ht to tex file; then biber; then tex4ht again 
mk4ht oolatex $filename.out-ent "xhtml, superscript, charset=utf-8"  -utf8
biber $filename.out-ent
mk4ht oolatex $filename.out-ent "xhtml, superscript, charset=utf-8"  -utf8

#convert resulting odt file to docx
#(LibreOffice must NOT be open for this to work)
soffice --headless --invisible --convert-to docx $filename.out-ent.odt
```

## result

When I run it on my system (using MacTeX 2018, packages updated on January 13, 2018, using TeX Live Utility), the output is a `.docx` file that mixes good output with gobbledygook like "ntity1589Δ1" (followed by two "images" that do not render and contain the words "The picture can't be displayed") caused by the fact that my setup cannot understand macros that use Unicode in the macro name because it converts all Unicode characters in the original TeX file to `\entity{....}`.

After the total gobbledygook, the rest of the file looks something like this:

> This is a test file using a macro whose name uses Arabic Unicode characters: العربية. Then we can try it as a block quote:
>
> أن يبد
>   entity1589أ
>
> If that doesn’t work, here is some non-Arabic Unicode: *kitābat al-ʿarabiyyah bi-l-ḥurūf al-lātīniyyah*, καὶ τὸ στοιχείοις Ἑλληνικοῖς γράφειν...

As you can see, that is pretty good, except for the failure to deal with the Unicode-named macro.

If I comment out the part of the TeX file that defines the macro using a Unicode character, then the initial gobbledygook disappears, and only this last part, beginning with "This is a test file," remains.

## question

My question is this: Is there a way to keep using my Unicode macro-names and just change the workflow in order to produce a `.docx` file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the process can be simplified considerably. `tex4ht` supports full Unicode with XeTeX and LuaTeX engines, so it is not necessary to use Perl scripts for the pre-processing. Another change to your workflow is that the recommended way to produce ODT document from `tex4ht` is to use `make4ht -f odt` script, which fixes lot of issues that can happen during the conversion.

I would also modify your macro, it is better to use text commands for < and > than math:

```
\makeatother\newcommand{%
 \ﺹ%
 }[1]{\textless #1\textgreater}
```

But I think the output is wrong anyway. Probably because of font shaping in the output, because it is represented differently in the XML than in the rendered document.

One thing with XeTeX support in `tex4ht` is that the support for non-Latin scripts must be explicitly loaded using the `\xeuniuseblock` command. It can be used in the configuration file, like `myconfig.cfg`:

```
\Preamble{xhtml}
\xeuniuseblock{Greek}
\xeuniuseblock{Arabic}
\makeatletter
\ConfigureEnv{arab}{\@rltrue}{\@rlfalse}{}{}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\EndPreamble
```

The names to be used should be OpenType script names (these are used as value for `script` key in Fontspec font selection commands).

The configuration for `arab` environment enables RTL direction for the enclosed text. This will produce right aligned text with correct text direction for Arabic.

The last bit is the Biber support. It can be requested in the `make4ht` build file. It can be even required conditionally, in order to save the compilation time. Save the following file as `main.out.mk4`:

```
Make:add("biber", "biber ${input}")
if mode=="draft" then
Make:htlatex {}
else
Make:htlatex {}
Make:biber {}
Make:htlatex {}
Make:htlatex {}
end
```

The file can be compiled using the following command:

```
make4ht -ux -f odt  -c myconfig.cfg main.out.tex
```

The subsequent compilations may use the `draft` mode, which use only one LaTeX compilation and doesn't use Biber, which results in huge saving of the compilation time:

```
make4ht -uxm draft -f odt  -c myconfig.cfg main.out.tex
```

The result in LibreOffice:

[image]

You can see that the macro output is really strange.

Comment: Thank you, this is great! Now about fixing the formatting, I wonder if it has to do with right-to-left issues. When I swap `\textless` and `\textgreater`, it's almost right, except that the angle bracket on the right should appear in the Arabic font (which presumably would flip it the correct way) at the end of the line on the left. Also, Arabic block quotes would ideally be R-to-L by default in the output.

Comment: Adding more Arabic in the block quote after the macro fixes the formatting problem (once I had swapped < and >), so it suggests that the real lingering problem is how an Arabic paragraph is formatted in the output, particularly punctuation at the end (i.e., left-most extreme) of a line.

Comment: @AlexRoberts I think I've found the solution for the direction issues. See the updated answer. It is just necessary to place the `quote` environment inside `arab`, so it has an effect.

Comment: @AlexRoberts I've also fixed a bug in the configuration for the quote environment in `tex4ht` sources, so the direction stuff will work after `tex4ht` update in TL, which should happen in few days.

Comment: I can't seem to reproduce what you're getting with the new lines in `myconfig.cfg`. It still has the old strange output, even when I put the `quote` environment inside the `arab` environment. (Or did you mean that it will only work after the TL update?) Also, is there a way that does not involve swapping the nesting of the `quote` and `arab` environments? My (huge) document has many instances of `arab`-environments inside of `quote`-environments, usually because in a single `quote` I quote the Arabic text followed by my English translation.

Comment: @AlexRoberts it seems that it works even if the `arab` is inside `quote`. but yes, it will work only after the `tex4ht` update.

Comment: Great! Then I'll wait a couple days to try it again. Many thanks for this solution!