# How to prevent the loss of a Greek Unicode character when converting to ODT using tex4ht

Tags: unicode, tex4ht, greek

To convert from XeLaTeX source to `.odt`/`.docx`, I am using the [solution provided by Michal Hoftich](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/470415/using-tex4ht-to-convert-from-xelatex-source-that-uses-unicode-named-macros-to-wo). (See there for MWE and the solution by @michal.h21.)

That setup works great for converting Unicode, but I noticed that it gobbles up the Greek Unicode character ἀ. That is, `ἀ` in the source yields nothing in the output.

Is there a simple way to fix that bug?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is caused by a bug in the code that `tex4ht` uses for registering Unicode ranges. It skipped the first character in the range, which `ἀ` happens to be, with Unicode value of `0x1F00`. I've fixed that in `tex4ht` sources, but it may take few days before the update is installed in TL. In the meantime, you can use the declaration for an individual character in the custom config file:

```
\xeuniregisterchar{"1F00}
```

This code makes the character active. It can then output special code for `tex4ht` with the Unicode value.

Sample document:

[image]

Comment: Great, thank you, and thanks for the quick fix!

Comment: @AlexRoberts thanks for the report, this bug was around for quite some time, but nobody reported it.