# tex4ht produces a corrupted file when a \label and a \ref to that label use a double-hyphen

Tags: cross-referencing, tex4ht

When my document has a `figure` with a `\label{aa--bb}` or any other label that uses two hyphens (-) in a row (--), `tex4ht` produces a corrupt `.odt` file. Is there a way to fix this bug?

## MWE

Using the same same setup as I did in an [earlier question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/470415/using-tex4ht-to-convert-from-xelatex-source-that-uses-unicode-named-macros-to-wo), concatenate `head.tex`, `main.tex`, and `tail.tex` then compile it using the command given by Michal Hoftich (@michal.h21) in his answer to that question.

`main.tex`:

```
%!TEX TS-program = xelatex
%!TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode

\documentclass[12pt]{memoir}
\usepackage{ifmtarg}
\usepackage{calc}

%Greek
\newcommand{\greek}[1]{#1}
\newcommand{\gk}[1]{#1}

%Arabic
\newcommand{\ar}[1]{#1}
\newenvironment{arab}{}{}

% Bibliography etc
\usepackage[american]{babel} 
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[notes,
        alldates=       comp,
        backend=        biber,
        bibwarn=        false,
        cmsdate=        both, % reprints: print `origdate` as well as `year`
        compresspages=  true,
        doi=            false,
        eprint=     false,
        ibidtracker=        true,
        inheritshorthand,       % feature added for me by D.Fussner
        isbn=           false,
        mincrossrefs =  2,
        shorthandibid,
        strict=     true,
        url=            true,
        usetranslator=  true,
        uniquename= true
    ]{biblatex-chicago}
\addbibresource{/Users/alexandre/Dropbox/bib-dbs/alexhistory.bib}
\addbibresource{/Users/alexandre/Dropbox/bib-dbs/alexhistory-NEW.bib}

\usepackage{textcomp} % For angle brackets `\textlangle` and `\textrangle`

\begin{document}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%    My text goes here:    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

Fig.~\ref{aa--bb}.

\begin{figure}[p]
\begin{center}
\label{aa--bb}
\end{center}
\end{figure}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%    My text ends here:    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\end{document}
```

In the directory, I then include `myconfig.cfg` (again from Michal Hoftich, for the purposes of making Arabic text appear properly):

```
\Preamble{xhtml}
\xeuniuseblock{Greek}
\xeuniuseblock{Arabic}
\makeatletter
\ConfigureEnv{arab}{\@rltrue}{\@rlfalse}{}{}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\EndPreamble
```

Then I run the command:

```
make4ht -ux -f odt  -c myconfig.cfg main.out.tex
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that the used label is printed in a comment in the generated file (`t4htlink` is replaced with correct element by a post-processing script):

```
<!--l. 48--><text:p text:style-name="Text-body">Fig. <t4htlink
href="#x1-1doc"><!--tex4ht:ref: aa--bb --></t4htlink>.
```

This causes an invalid XML, because comment cannot contain the `--` string. The simplest solution is to not print the label in a comment. Try the following cfg file:

```
\Preamble{xhtml}
\xeuniuseblock{Greek}
\xeuniuseblock{Arabic}
\makeatletter
\ConfigureEnv{arab}{\@rltrue}{\@rlfalse}{}{}
\Configure{ref}{\Link}{\EndLink}{}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\EndPreamble
```

The important line is this one:

```
\Configure{ref}{\Link}{\EndLink}{}
```

It configures the `\ref` command to print only the link, without a comment.

Comment: That did it -- thank you! Incidentally, I realized while trying out your solution that for this to produce a figure number (even using `xetex` and not `tex4ht`), I need to include a `\caption{...}` in the figure.

Comment: @AlexRoberts you are welcome! Yes, the label needs some command that sets counter to work correctly, but it was not related to your issue.